# Comment on dit « It's none of my business » en français ?

Tags: expressions

Est-ce qu'il y a une expression en français comme « It's none of my business » ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Je crois que l'expression principale est « ce n'est pas (de) mes affaires ». Dans un contexte plus familier, on peut aussi dire « ce n'est pas (de) mes oignons ».

Dans un même ordre d'idées, mais lorsque l'on veut dire à quelqu'un « *it's none of your business* », on pourrait également dire « mêle-toi de tes affaires » or « occupe-toi de tes oignons ».

Comment: Je pense que le *de* est de trop. On dit *ce n'est pas mes affaires / mes oignons*

Comment: @LaurentG. Peut-être est-ce une différence régionale. Au Québec, on dit bien [*ce n'est pas de mes affaires*](http://www.lapresse.ca/le-soleil/affaires/actualite-economique/201112/01/01-4473360-depart-de-cgi-ce-nest-pas-de-mes-affaires-dit-labeaume.php).

Comment: Il m'est arrivé d'entendre _échalottes_ à la place d'_oignons_.

Answer (score 8):

Autres possibilités, en plus des suggestions de Kareen :

«Cela ne me regarde pas», «Cela ne me concerne pas»